# PHP: Insert data from form and another table in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data from a form and another table where `inv_id = "'.$inv.'"` are in the same table `"history"` `($inv` is data input  from form) (sorry for my bad english)

Actually my query:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO istoric SET id_user = '".$user."',id_equipment = '".$nr_inv."',start = '".$startdate."',end = '".$enddate."',comment = '".$comment."'"; 
$id = "INSERT INTO `istoric`(`condition`) SELECT `status` FROM `echipament`WHERE `nr_inventar` = '".$nr_inv."'";
```

How to combine two query? Now this query insert data in two different rows.

History table:

[image]

Comment: you want to update the condition of the table istoric with the value of status echipament?

Comment: If you have trouble using the english stackoverflow or you find it difficult to explain and understand, you can use the portuguese. Also, regarding your query, and depending on how the database is implemented, you could consider making the condition field as a foreign key for the echipament table, instead of what appears to be a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub-query to generate the value for the `condition` field:

```
INSERT INTO 
  `istoric`
SET 
  `id_user` = '".$user."',
  `id_equipment` = '".$nr_inv."',
  `start` = '".$startdate."',
  `end` = '".$enddate."',
  `comment` = '".$comment."', 
  `condition` = (
    SELECT 
      `status` 
    FROM 
      `echipament`
    WHERE 
      `nr_inventar` = '".$nr_inv."'
  );
```

Also based on how you've formatted your query, you should used prepared statements for your queries instead of injecting the variables directly into your query